# FROM_UNIXTIME return null with mysql ubuntu

Tags: mysql

To select birthrate from the time stamp from my table it returns null value.
My query is as below in which i want only year From it, which is 1969.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(-8035200, "%Y") AS `birthtitle`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix time cannot be negative.

To solve your problem add 84600 * 3650 to your number (3650 days), then subtract 3650 days from the date.